# Arduino: how can I stop while() when bluetooth send a data?

Tags: c++, code-optimization

I have learned Arduino for a month, and I want to bulid a car with 2 modes,
Remote and Auto. Auto mode needs to have while() loop, so it can receive data from sensors. When I choose Auto mode via bluetooth, it keeps looping and it won't stop when I choose the Remote mode. Here's the part code:

```
char mode;

void loop()
{
    while(serial1.available())
    {
        char control = serial.read();
        if(control == 'r') mode = 'r';     // r stand for Remote Mode
        if(control == 'a') mode = 'a';     // a stand for Auto Mode

        if(mode == 'r') remoteMode(control);

        while(mode = 'a')
        {
            int IR = analogRead(A10);
            float U1cmMsec,U2cmMsec;
            long U1microsec = u1.timing();
            long U2microsec = u2.timing();
            U1cmMsec = u1.convert(U1microsec, Ultrasonic::CM);
            U2cmMsec = u2.convert(U2microsec, Ultrasonic::CM);

            robot(U1cmMsec, U2cmMsec,IR);

            /*
            Here is the code to stop while() that I don't know how
            to program.
            I have tried:

            if(serial1.read() != 'a') break; 

            But it will stop while(), because it will waits for
            bluetooth send data to arduino board. 
            And if I take this line off, it will keeps while() and
            nothing can stop it.
            So, what am I supposed to do?
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this line:

```
while(mode = 'a') {
```

What you are saying there is not what you think you are saying.  You are confusing `=` (assignment) with `==` (comparison).

You are basically saying "While I assign 'a' to the variable 'mode' and 'a' is not 0 ...", which of course will always be true.

Instead you want:

```
while (mode == 'a') {
```

or, "While the variable 'mode' contains the letter 'a' ..."

Now you just need to program in some way of changing the value of `mode` within your while loop.

You can read more on while loops here:

- http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/the-while-loop

Answer (score 0):

The `while(serial1.available())` can be turned into an `if`: the loop function is already executed in a loop, as the name hints :-)

And unnest the inner `while`.

here it is at high level, which is probably easier to understand:

`void loop() {
  static char mode; /*notice the "static"*/
  if (character_available())
    update_mode();
  if (mode == 'r')
    do_one_iteration_in_remote_mode();
  else if (mode == 'a')
    do_one_iteration_in_auto_mode();
}`

Just make sure that you do not loop inside neither `do_one_iteration_in_remote_mode()` nor `do_one_iteration_in_auto_mode()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced both 'mode' and 'control' (they were identical) with a single variable, `btChar`. At the end of `setup()`, wait for a transmission to be received before entering the main loop.

Once the main loop begins, a while loop executes until the serial receives a new transmission. Once it is received it is read, btChar is updated and the main loop starts again.

```
char btChar;

void setup()
{
/* AT THE END OF SETUP() */

// Wait in setup for first BT transmission

    while (!serial1.available())
    { /* do nothing */ }
    btChar = serial1.read();
}

void loop()
{
    while(!serial1.available())
    {
    // Program will stay in this 'while' loop until
    //    a new BT character is recv'd

        switch(btChar)
        {
            case('a'):
            {
            // do the 'auto' stuff
                break;
            }
            case('r'):
            {
            // do the 'remote' stuff
                break;
            }
            default: // this 'block' is not essential
            {
            // you end up here if neither 'a' nor 'r' was received
            }
        }
    }
    btChar = serial1.read();
}
```

You can adapt the setup while-loop further to make sure that the main loop doesn't begin until the a correct character is received - change the line to:

```
while ((!serial1.available())&&(btChar != 'a')&&(btChar != 'r'))
```

Using a `switch-case` statement within the main while-loop is not essential, and I included it out of interest more than necessity. You can use `if` statements instead, with one for 'a' and one for 'r'. However, in the event that you have a third or fourth (or more-th) mode then a switch-case statement, in my view, looks easier to read.